# Extending the root with another partition (website's server, on production)

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount, websites

I work for a media whose website gets around 300k views/day, installed on an OVH server.

When we've got the server, it was said to have 2x 500 GB of SSD storage, so we went with it and installed everything without checking which partition has space in it. After months in production, we're now unable to backup the website because the server runs out of space. After some quick check…

`df -h` gives this:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  1.3M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/md3         20G   13G  6.1G  67% /
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md2        487M  213M  246M  47% /boot
/dev/md4        449G   70M  426G   1% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  510M  6.1M  504M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/0
```

First thing I notice is that `/` has only 20 GB mounted to it. Since the website is under `/var/www/`, it appears that it falls under that partition.

Second thing, 450 GB are mounted on `/home`, which is pretty weird for a server distribution of Ubuntu. It isn't supposed to host users and their desktop, downloads, etc., or is it?

What is needed now is a way to extend `/` or `/var/www/` with `/dev/md4` without losing data, and preferably without downtime (or much downtime, otherwise there might be SEO repercussions).

I have thought about copying `/var/www` to `/home/www/` and then creating a sym-link between them, but I prefer to get some advice and suggestions prior of doing anything. I'm not the assigned dev (but an Editorial assistant, and there is no dev actually), so the duty falls on me and I don't want to screw things up; especially that there is no backup at the current time.

Another thing that I wonder about is where the 2nd 500 GB SSD storage is gone. I'll ask if it's been put as RAID-0 but I have some doubts.

Thank you.

Comment: Before editing partitions, if it's possible, **do a backup**.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` doesn't show your second disk?

Comment: Your clue is the md device, so RAID.

Comment: @guillermo-chamorro and @ubfan, thank you very much for the clues. `sudo fdisk -l` gives two disks with partitions on RAID (EFI, 3 parititons on RAID, then SWAP). One mystery solved. Thanks. (And sorry for the edit, I've hit Enter instead of Shift+Enter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lost space was found by checking `fdisk -l`. The SSD was on RAID-0.

About moving the website content to the SSD, the solution turned out to be the symbolic link. So here is how I changed place for the website content without downtime and without moving or editing partitions:

1. Copy website's content to a folder in the big partition
   `mkdir /home/SiteName/`
   `cp -vrp /var/www/html/* /home/SiteName`
2. Move website's folder to a new folder (just in case you need to set back the old folder)
   `mv /var/www/html /var/www/html2`
3. Create a symbolic link from to the new folder to replace the old folder
   `ln -sv /home/SiteName/ /var/www/html`
4. Check if symbolic link has been correctly created
   `ls -l /var/www/html`
5. Delete old files
   `rm /var/www/html2 -r`

There has been a Wordpress plugin that stopped working after this (Classic Editor) but it got fixed after rebooting the server.

Thanks to members who gave me clues.